# Conditional animation in SwiftUI stops working

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have this code:

```
Group{
   if self.done{
      Image(systemName: "plus").font(.system(size: 40)).foregroundColor(.gray)
         .padding().overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3)).opacity(0.6)
   }
   else{
      Button(action: {self.showSearchTrash = 1}){
         Image(systemName: "plus").font(.system(size: 40)).foregroundColor(green)
            .padding().overlay(Circle().stroke(green, lineWidth: 3).scaleEffect(1+self.animationAmount).animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)).onAppear {self.animationAmount = 0.1})
      }
   }
}.padding(.bottom, 5)
```

And the intention is that if `self.done` is `false`, the circle on the plus button will expand and contract indefinitely.

This works. However, if I use a toggle to set `self.done` to be `true` and then turn it back to `false`, the animation no longer occurs. I know that the issue is not with the toggle, because it does return to being green.

Also, the lack of `.` before `green` is intentional - I defined a specific Color `green`.

Any idea why the animation stops working/how to fix this?

Comment: can you add more code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `Animation` in the `withAnimation` block and create separate functions for starting/stopping the animation.

Here is a possible solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var done = false
    @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Done", isOn: $done)
            plusImage
                .opacity(done ? 0.6 : 1)
                .foregroundColor(done ? .gray : .green)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: startAnimation)
        .onChange(of: done) { done in
            if done {
                stopAnimation()
            } else {
                startAnimation()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var plusImage: some View {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
            .font(.system(size: 40))
            .padding()
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3)
                    .scaleEffect(1 + animationAmount)
            )
    }
}
```

```
private extension ContentView {
    func startAnimation() {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever()) {
            animationAmount = 0.1
        }
    }
    
    func stopAnimation() {
        withAnimation {
            animationAmount = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually works fine *as-is* with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1, so you might observe either bug of new iOS version or result of some other code.

Anyway, I would added turn-offs scaling on button disappear:

```
Button(action: {}){
    Image(systemName: "plus").font(.system(size: 40)).foregroundColor(green)
        .padding().overlay(Circle().stroke(green, lineWidth: 3).scaleEffect(1+self.animationAmount).animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)))
}
.onAppear {self.animationAmount = 0.1}    // << put here !!
.onDisappear {self.animationAmount = 0}   // << add this !!
```

[image: demo]